# How to handle time index with custom time series datastructure

Tags: scala, time-series, scala-breeze

I want to implement my own time series data structure and I want to do it using [ScalaNLP Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze). Now my first thought was to do this using a type like this:

```
type RowNumber = Long
Map[LocalDateTime, RowNumber]
```

However after reading more about breeze available data structures i found `Counter2` which seems to be exactly what I need.

Now I do have two questions:

1. Would implementing a time series abstraction on top of breeze using `Counter` and `Counter2` be the best way to do this?
2. Are all matrix operations supported on `Counter2` (docs says only array operations are supported for Counter)?

Answer (score 1):

Counter2 supports most basic matrix operations: arithmetic, slicing, matrix multiply. It doesn't support matrix decompositions or solve.

Short of using a SparseVector or a CSCMatrix with appropriate integer indices for your keys, I don't see anything better in Breeze.